# Django Ajax updated Table loosing sortable function

Tags: django, ajax

I'm using this plugin to make my HTML table sortable and it works great.

```
<script src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
```

You can call it by adding sortable in the table class

```
<table id='myTable' class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered fixed_header sortable">
```

But when I'm updating the table with AJAX after filtering, the table updates correctly but looses the sortable functionality.

Do I have to re-import the script somewhere ?
I have tried to place it in my home.html page and of course in my filter.html page which is rendered after the Ajax call.

I also tried those things :
[Sortable function when content is updated via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608408/sortable-function-when-content-is-updated-via-ajax?rq=2)

[Why would javascript fail when called dynamically (Ajax)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960594/why-would-javascript-fail-when-called-dynamically-ajax?rq=2)

Here is my AJAX

```
    <script src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
   <form id="searchform" method="POST" action="{% url "article-filter" %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text"  id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch">
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
        $("#searchform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {txtSearch: $('#txtSearch').val(), csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },});
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "article-filter/",
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#myTable').html(data.html_table);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is the Table in home.html and filter.html

```
table id='myTable' class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered fixed_header sortable">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr id='tableHeader'>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">City</th>
      <th scope="col">State</th>
      <th scope="col">Zipcode</th>
      <th scope="col">Created At</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

{% if records %}
    {% for record in records %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ record.first_name }} {{ record.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ record.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ record.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ record.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ record.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ record.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ record.zipcode }}</td>
            <td>{{ record.created_at }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'record' record.id %}">{{ record.id }}</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}


      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please write more about your code especially html, views and js files. also what's the exact problem??

Answer (score 0):

I finally work with it.

Named my table in home.html id='myTable'

Named the updated table on filter.html id='myTable2'

And change my AJAX call like this :

```
<script>
        $("#searchform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {txtSearch: $('#txtSearch').val(), csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },});
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "article-filter/",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            $("#myTable").html(data.html_table);
            sorttable.makeSortable(document.getElementById("myTable2"));
        }
    });
})
</script>
```